# How and Where does system tracks( or keeps ) the softwares( or simple files) that are getting installed

Tags: c#, windows, operating-system

1)Suppose I am installing a software (say Microsoft Visual Studio) and a movie torrent, where does my windows will keep information about this (that a software and a file is getting installed in the system).

2) Is there a way to get this location or information using c#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1)Suppose I am installing a software (say Microsoft Visual Studio) and
>   a movie torrent, where does my windows will keep information about
>   this (that a software and a file is getting installed in the system).

The installed software information is stored under `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall`.

> 2) Is there a way to get this location or information using c#.

Yes, you can `using Microsoft.Win32` and do as following:

```
        var key = Registry.LocalMachine
            .OpenSubKey("Software")
            .OpenSubKey("Microsoft")
            .OpenSubKey("Windows")
            .OpenSubKey("CurrentVersion")
            .OpenSubKey("Uninstall");

        foreach(var n in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            var name = key.OpenSubKey(n).GetValue("DisplayName");
            if (name != null) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(name);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(n);
            }
        }
```

Comment: While this works for well-behaved programs, it's entirely up to the installer if it adds an uninstall program to the list. There might be more software installed than what this listing shows.

Comment: @AndersAbel Yes, with nasty programs to detect, the only way is to `search` for them. Both under the registry and path.